# didSet not updating NSImage

Tags: swift, appkit, nsbutton, didset

I am trying to update the Image of an NSButton(Image) through a toggle in my storyboard. The NSButton Image is not changing though.

Here my ViewController IBAction Code:

```
    @IBAction func ButtonState(_ sender: NSSwitch) {
    let stateOfButton = sender.state
    if (stateOfButton.rawValue == 1){
        testButton.isEnabled = true

    
    }
    else{
        testButton.isEnabled = false

    }
}
```

Here a snippet from my NSButton Class with the modifications:

```
override var isEnabled: Bool{
    didSet{
        if(self.isEnabled){
            self.image = NSImage(named: "TestEnabled")
            print("TestEnable")
        }
        else{
            self.image = NSImage(named: "TestDisabled")
            self.state = NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 0)
            print("NoEnable")
        }
        
    }
```

The print statements are executed on toggling the switch but the image is not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double check that both of the named images exist. Below is a prettified version of your code and it works as expected:

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: MyButton!
    
    @IBAction func switchClicked(_ sender: NSSwitch) {
        button.isEnabled = sender.state == .on
    }
}

class MyButton: NSButton {
    override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            image = isEnabled
                ? NSImage(named: NSImage.statusAvailableName)
                : NSImage(named: NSImage.statusUnavailableName)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Button switch demo]

Answer (score -1):

for set image in button you should use that

```
yourButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: There's no `setImage` on AppKit NSButton, you're confusing it with the UIKit counterpart.